# Symfony 5.1 service registration depending on database data

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, symfony5

I'm using Symfony 5.1 and want to build a plugin system for my application.
The code of core application is placed in the `src/` directory, the plugins will be stores in the `custom/` directory.

The structure for a plugin is predefined and looks like this:

```
custom
|--SomePlugin
  |--Controller
  |--Subscriber
  |--...
  |--SomePlugin.php
```

There is also a database with a table that contains the status of the plugin, whether it is active or not.

```
| name   | version | status |
| ------ | ------- | ------ |
| string | string  | bool   |
```

### How to load services from plugin namespaces

My application is already be setup to load services from the default `App` namespace - also controllers are loaded automatically. Since loading of those services and controllers depends on the status received from the database, I used the following customization of the Kernel.

```
// src/Kernel.php

namespace App;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    // ...

    protected function configureRoutes(RoutingConfigurator $routes): void
    {
        $activePlugins = $this->getActivePlugins();

        $customDirectories = scandir($this->getProjectDir() . '/custom/');

        foreach ($customDirectories as $customDirectory) {
            if (!in_array($customDirectory, ['.', '..']) &&
                is_dir($this->getProjectDir() . '/custom/' . $customDirectory . '/Controller/')) {

                $prefix = call_user_func([$customDirectory . '\\' . $customDirectory, 'name']);
                $prefix = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '-', $prefix);
                $prefix = strtolower($prefix);

                if(in_array($prefix, $activePlugins)) {
                    $routes->import('../custom/' . $customDirectory . '/Controller/', 'annotation')
                        ->namePrefix($prefix . '_');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

The `getActivePlugins()` function returns an array with all active plugins. If a plugin is active, the route should be registers. **This works fine.**

But... to configure the services, I have to use the `configureContainer()` function.

```
// src/Kernel.php

// ...

protected function configureContainer(ContainerConfigurator $container): void
{
   $activePlugins = $this->getActivePlugins();

   // ...
}

// ...
```

The problem is: at this time the kernel is not booted, so the `getActivePlugins()` function has no access to the container and I cannot use Doctrine to fetch the data from the database.

Is there a way to register the services **after** the kernel is booted?

Comment: No.  You cannot add services after the kernel is booted.  In fact, you need to be aware that services and routes are 'compiled' into cache directories.  If you had thoughts of being able to enable a plugin in the database and automatically have it's services available then you will be disappointed.  You will need something to clear and rebuild the cache after each plugin change.  If you can live with that requirement then you will need to setup your own database connection for configureContainer to use.

Comment: And what about a second compilation of the kernel? First register the 'core' services and after that, register the plugin services?

Comment: What about it?  You still can't add a service to a compiled container.  You need to clear the cache to modify the container.

Comment: You're welcome to use some kind of container builder that gathers all activated plugins during the compilation

Comment: This is a problem that many Content Management Systems (CMS) have to solve as well. You might take a look at other CMS's that are based in Symfony to see how they solve it, but Cerad is right, you will beed to clear and rebuild the cache after each change. Also be aware that secondary caches like OPCache and others will cause difficulty in the process.